# cannot read pipe of undefined when using debounceTime

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to cause an event to fire when an input box has no value typed into it after 1 second.

```
 @ViewChild('input') input;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.input
           .valueChanges
           .pipe(
               debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged()
           )
            .subscribe(value => {
                if(value) {
                     //do stuff
                }
            })
    }


vendor.js:70063 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at SimpleDomainSearchComponent.ngAfterViewInit (main.js:8036)
    at callHook (vendor.js:68662)
    at callHooks (vendor.js:68626)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (vendor.js:68566)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:75092)
    at refreshComponent (vendor.js:76493)
    at refreshChildComponents (vendor.js:74733)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:75068)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (vendor.js:76404)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:75039)
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:70063
```

I have followed different tutorials to find the cause of this but I cannot, I have changed the input to FormControl and that has still caused the pipe to be undefined. the input isn't null, ive debugged it.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the full code or a stackblitz? What are you passing in to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) without using ViewChild.

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="input">
```

```js
input = new FormControl('');
```

With that you will have access to the `valueChanges` prop.